# Searching Multiple Terms

Tags: search, grep, regex

I know that `grep -E 'termA|termB' files` allows me to search multiple files for `termA OR termB`. What I would like to do instead is search for `termA AND termB`. They do not have to be on the same line as long as the two terms exists within the same file. Essentially a "search within result" feature.

I know I can pipe the results of one grep into another but that seems slow when going over many files.

```
grep -l "termA" * | xargs grep -l "termB" | xargs grep -E -H -n --color "termA|termB"
```

Hopefully the above isn't the only way to do this.

It would be extra nice if this could work on Windows (have cygwin) and Linux. I don't mind installing a tool to perform this task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use awk for this. Simply set a flag per match you're looking for, then check to see if all the flags have been set.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: `/regex1/ { flag1=1 }`

Comment: Thanks, I believe this will do what I want with some manipulation.